# How can I delete my app review & rating?

Tags: store, app-review

I'm a developer, and I implemented a rate and review feature on my phone. I accidentally rated my own app, is it possible to remove this rating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your review, but there's no mechanism to retract a review at this time form the phone.

What you can do is log into the Windows Store from your PC, navigate to your app's page, and you'll see your review with an **update** and a **clear** button. Pressing "clear" clears the review and gives message:

> Your review has been cleared, [yourname]

It may take a while for the reviews to show as updated.